# ExecuteUpdateAsync with query on the new value

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, sql-update, ef-core-7.0

I'm trying to migrate some old code that is still using `foreach` to update N values.
I have been reading a lot about ExecuteUpdateAsync but i can't seem to understand if my use case is actually supported or not, every attempt i do seems to generate the same error

> The LINQ expression could not be translated. Either rewrite the query
> in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation
> explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable',
> 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync

This is my Update method, i'm trying to pay special attention to the performance.

```
public async Task Update(IEnumerable<StockDTO> dtos)
{
    var ids = dtos.Select(d => d.ProductStockIdentiferId);
    var StockTypes = dtos.Select(d => (int)d.StockType);
    
    await _dbcontext.Stocks
        .Where(s => 
                ids.Contains(s.ProductStockIdentiferId) &&
                StockTypes.Contains(s.StockTypeId))
        .ExecuteUpdateAsync(setters =>
            setters.SetProperty(
                stock => stock.Value,
                stock => dtos.First(x =>
                    x.ProductStockIdentiferId == stock.ProductStockIdentiferId).Value));
}

public record StockDTO
{
    public StockType StockType { get; set; }
    public long Value { get; set; }
    public int ProductStockIdentiferId { get; set; }
}

public partial class Stock
{
    public StockType StockType { get; set; }
    public int StockTypeId { get; set; }
    public long Value { get; set; }
    public int ProductStockIdentiferId { get; set; }
}
```

This code works if i just set the new `Value` to a static number, and i understand the EF error, since i had to change from `Where().Any()` to do `Selects()` in the beginning, but i don't know how can i get the corresponding `dto.Value` without using a `foreach`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic you are trying to achieve doesn't seem like it's going to work with two separate lists. You have three values per DTO, and these need to be corresponded.

You need a Table Valued Parameter here, in order to pass a pair of values per row to join on.

First define a Table Type. For efficiency sake, it's worthwhile to define a primary key on the join columns, which you need to do inline.

```cs
CREATE TYPE dbo.StockDTO (
    ProductStockIdentiferId int NOT NULL,
    StockType int NOT NULL,
    Value bigint NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ProductStockIdentiferId, StockType)
);
```

Then create a function which can turn your DTO list into a TVP, and return an `IQueryable` so you can compose it.

```cs
public IQueryable<StockDTO> GetStockTvp(YourDbContext dbContext, IEnumerable<StockDTO> dtos, string paramName)
{
    var table = new DataTable { Columns = {
        { "ProductStockIdentiferId", typeof(int) },
        { "StockType", typeof(int) },
        { "Value", typeof(long) },
    } };
    foreach (var dto in dtos)
    {
        table.Rows.Add(dto.ProductStockIdentiferId, dto.StockType, dto.Value);
    }
    var parm = SqlParameter(paramName, SqlDbType.Structured) { TypeName = "dbo.StockDTO", Value = table };
    var query = dbContext.Set<StockDTO>.FromSqlRaw("SELECT * FROM @" + paramName, parm);
    return query;
}
```

For EF Core 7.0 or below, ensure the `StockDTO` class has been mapped in your `DbContext` configuration.

For EF Core 8.0+, you can now use an unmapped type

```
var query = dbContext.Database.SqlQueryRaw<StockDTO>("SELECT * FROM @" + paramName, parm);
```

---

Now you can compose that `IQueryable`

```cs
public async Task Update(IEnumerable<StockDTO> dtos)
{
    var tvp = GetStockTvp(_dbContext, dtos, "@dtos"); // make sure this is a separate step or it won't compose
    
    await _dbcontext.Stocks
        .Join(tvp, (stock, dto) => 
                stock.ProductStockIdentiferId == dto.ProductStockIdentiferId
                && stock.StockTypeId == dto.StockType,
              (stock, dto) => new {stock, dto })
        .ExecuteUpdateAsync(setters => setters
            .SetProperty(
                stockAndDto => stockAndDto.stock.Value,
                stockAndDto => stockAndDto.dtoValue
             )
         );
}
```

Comment: Seems a bit confusing in the sense that dbcontext will have stock and StockDTO? which are almost the same and in the end StockDTO was just meant to be used as a DTO and not really a SQL Type. Wasnt familiared with this approach tho, so thank you for the insight! I suppose you don't see a simpler way to achieve what i need?

Comment: Yes, you need both a table and a table type. Another option could be to use XML or JSON and shred it on the server side. But this may not be as efficient, although it doesn't require a table type to be declared, also not sure exactly how to call `.nodes` or `OPENJSON` respectively using EF Core.